# Set LENGTH of a Meta Value in args for WP get_users()

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to count all users that their mobile_phone length is greater than 5. This is my code but it is not working. Can you please help?

```
count(get_users(array(
'meta_key' => 'mobile_phone',
'length(meta_value)' => 5,
'meta_compare' => '>',
'fields' => 'ID'
)))
```

Comment: This doesn't look right to me.. 'length(meta_value)' => 5,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_users()` return an array of all users, so you can filter it after using `array_filter`

**functions.php**

```
function get_my_users() {
    $users = get_users();

    $users = array_filter(
        $users,
        function( $user ) {
            return strlen( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'mobile_phone', true ) ) > 5;
        }
    );

    return $users;
}
```

Call it

```
count( get_my_users() )
```

It should return all users with 'mobile_phone' meta length greater, than 5